# Verifying method call with enum in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mockito, verification, mockito-kotlin

I'm trying to verify that a method is called with a given argument. That argument is a non-nullable enum type. So I get the exception `eq(SomeEnum.foo) must not be null`. Here is a sample what I'm trying to do:

```kotlin
enum class SomeEnum {
    foo, bar
}

open class MyClass {
    fun doSomething() {
        magic(SomeEnum.foo)
    }

    internal fun magic(whatever: SomeEnum) {}
}

@Test
fun mockitoBug() {
    val sut = spy(MyClass())
    sut.doSomething()
    verify(sut).magic(eq(SomeEnum.foo))
}
```

Capturing does not work too. What can I do or is that really a bug as I assume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Mockito was designed for Java, it doesn't play well with Kotlin's null checks. A good solution is to use the mockito-kotlin extensions library: https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin

It includes Kotlin versions of the matchers that won't return null. Add a dependency on mockito-kotlin and just make sure to import the Kotlin versions instead of the Java ones.

Comment: `org.mockito.kotlin.eq` is the method that needs to be imported

Comment: Yep I'm using `mockito-kotlin` as implied by the tag and `eq` method already. When I understand the code correctly then in case of enums null will be returned and that just works for primitive types

Comment: @rekire The body of `fun <T> eq(value: T): T` is `return ArgumentMatchers.eq(value) ?: value`. For enum, it returns the value passed in, not null.

Comment: Android Studio picked up the wrong `eq` method. You are right it works now